# Composer update error on Travis CI

Tags: github, composer-php, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I have a composer update error during in one of my Travis CI tests:
https://travis-ci.org/JoryHogeveen/view-admin-as/jobs/399186175

The weird thing is that it only keeps failing with this particular test. All other tests (running the same config) are working fine:
https://travis-ci.org/JoryHogeveen/view-admin-as/builds/399186171

Also, the same test for the PR build is also working fine:
https://travis-ci.org/JoryHogeveen/view-admin-as/builds/399186189

Error:

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                            
 Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d                                      

 fatal: git show-ref: bad ref HEAD (8a4672aca8db6d807905d695799ea7d83c8e5bba)
```

It would be awesome if anyone could help me or at least point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to clear a cache of this build?

Comment: Sometimes the fix is so much simpler than expected, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, refreshing the cache as [@rob006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812455/rob006) mentioned worked!